# Apache Proxy and Rewrite, append directory to URL

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, .htaccess, rewrite

I have a backend server running on `http://10.0.2.20/` from the local network, which serves similar to this:

```
/ (root)
|
|_user1/
| |_www/
| |_private/
|
|_user2/
  |_www/
  |_private/
(etc.)
```

Accessing `http://10.0.2.20/user1/` of course, contains 'www' and 'private' folders and is proxied through a public server using Apache's Reverse Proxy. I'd like it so the following happens:

`http://public-proxy-server/user1/` actually shows the content from `http://10.0.2.20/user1/www/` without indicating it in the URL. (/private/ would not be accessible via the public proxy server).

The key here, is for it to be dynamic, so all requests to `http://public-proxy-server/*/`should show content from `http://10.0.2.20/*/www/`. Again, the proxy currently works fine; below is the config:

*(On the public server)*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia full
        ProxyPass / http://10.0.2.20/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.2.20/
</VirtualHost>
```

*(On the backend server)*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...
        #this directory contains folders 'user1' and 'user2'
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is there content that depends on `30x` redirects to function (in other words; do you actually need that `ProxyPassReverse`)?  And how about content (images, CSS, javascript) that are linked with absolute paths from the content?

Comment: Well it's simply just proxying the content from an internal server, all files (images, stylesheets, etc) are served like it would be externally. There's no need to 'redirect' per se, but just 'rewrite' the URL internally. That's all I'm going for. To `serve the content of the '/user/www' folder without showing the 'www' in the URL`. The only (and main) problem is the wildcard. Basically I need the `DocumentRoot` on the proxy server to be set to `/username/www` (append the www). It doesn't matter if that happens on the public or proxy server. Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the reverse proxy server, use a `ProxyPassMatch`:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://10.0.2.20/$1/www/$2
```

And you'll probably still want the `/` root proxying, so keep that `ProxyPass` in place - just make sure it's **below** the `ProxyPassMatch`, since they're checked in order.

Comment: Ah, finally. Worked as intended. I was trying `mod_rewrite` and related. Even the `[P]` flag.